# Gatsby GraphiQL did't see images from Strapi 4

Tags: strapi, graphiql

I have a problem with Strapi and Gatsby GraphiQL. I was deploy Strapi on Heroku, create a content type and try to fetch some data, but Gatsby GraphiQL didn't see images. Why it's happening? Where is my mistake?

```
   {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-strapi",
      options: {
        apiURL: "https://thawing-beyond-49749.herokuapp.com",
        collectionTypes: [
          "api/main-page-slides",
        ],
        queryLimit: 1000,
      },
    },
```

[image: GraphiQL]

[image]

Comment: Strapi 4 was only recently released, I am almost certain, at this point `gatsby-source-strapi` only currently supports Strapi 3. For now, you should maybe use `gatsby-source-graphql` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`gatsby-source-strapi`](https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi) is only compatible with v3, as you can see in the repository:

> ⚠️ This version of `gatsby-source-strapi` is only compatible with Strapi
> v3 at the moment. We are currently working on a v4 compatible version.

That said, in the meantime, your only chance is to roll back to v3 and wait for a compatible plugin version, otherwise you won't be able to fetch the data properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply get images data in strapi v4+ by following graphql query =>>

images{
data{
id
attributes{
url
}
}
}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYAx7.png)